# Eliminar espacios en blanco inusuales en jTextField - Java

Tags: java, java-swing

**¿Cómo borrar espacios en blanco innecesarios o guiones innecesarios?**

Bien, tengo un `jTextField_ciudad` en el cual puedo escribir únicamente letras, espacios (`VK_SPACE`) y guiones (`VK_MINUS`).

**Código**:

```
private void textfield_ciudadKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        Character letra = evt.getKeyChar();
        if(Character.isLetter(letra) || (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) || 
          (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS)){
            evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(letra));
        }else{
           evt.consume();
        }

        if(textfield_ciudad.getText().length()>49){
            evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
        }
    }
```

¿Se puede capar que se pueda escribir un espacio seguido de otro espacio o un guión seguido de otro guión? Es decir: invalidar (Castilla--La   Mancha) validar (Castilla-La Mancha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes tomar el texto actual del `textfield_ciudad` y reemplazar los guiones y espacios por un guión y un espacio respectivamente, luego actualizar el texto del `textfield_ciudad`:

```
private void textfield_ciudadKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        Character letra = evt.getKeyChar();
        if(Character.isLetter(letra) || (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) || 
          (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS)){
            evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(letra));
        }else{
           evt.consume();
        }

       String texto = textfield_ciudad.getText();
              if( texto.length() > 0)
              //eliminar primer caracter si no es una letra
              if(!Character.isLetter(texto.charAt(0))){
                texto = texto.length() > 1 ? texto.substring(1) : "";
              }

              // reemplazar guiones duplicados por un guion
              texto = texto.replaceAll("[-]+", "-");
              // reemplazar espacios duplicados por un espacio
              texto = texto.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");



              textfield_ciudad.setText(texto);

        if(textfield_ciudad.getText().length()>49){
            evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Respuesta válida. ¿Y si quiero capar que el primer y el último caracter del jTextField sea una LETRA?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta y agregué una condición para quitar el primer caracter si no es una letra. Para verificar el último caracter debe usarse un evento diferente ya que si se hace dentro del mismo no hay forma de saber si el último caracter ingresado es efectivamente el último.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646) Me da la siguiente excepción.

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta. Lo había puesto en el orden incorrecto.

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el error :( El mismo. Creo que se debe cuando borro todo el jTextField, entonces error.

Comment: Ya agregué una condición que evalúa si campo no está vacío.